# Find the flaw in my proof that $z^2 =1$ has more than $2$ distinct solutions.

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ be any number that satisfies the equation $z^2=1$. Certainly, $z=\pm1$ are two possible solutions to this equation. I claim that $z^k$ is also a solution to this equation for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$, resulting in (probably) at least one other distinct solution (for example, the solution $z=(-1)^{\pi}$).

> **Proof:** Choose any $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $(z^k)^2=z^{2k}=(z^2)^k=1^k=1$, as desired.

So, can someone tell me what's wrong with my proof? I know that this has something to do with roots of unity and that this equation should only have 2 distinct solutions, so something must be wrong with my proof. Please bear in mind that I understand **very little** about complex numbers besides the definition that $i^2 = -1$. Thanks!

Comment: Once you allow $z$ to be a complex number, it is no longer true in general that $z^{2k}=(z^2)^k$. Take a look at [this old answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/104744/264).

Comment: Another way to look at this is that $z^k$ can be interpreted in more than one way when $k$ is a non-integer.  If you think about it, you're really taking $\exp(k \log z)$, and $\log z$ can also take multiple values in $\mathbb C$ (think $e^{2\pi i} = e^0$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1=\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=i^2=-1$$

The rule $\sqrt{x} \sqrt{y}=\sqrt{xy}$ is generally valid only if both $x,y \in +ve \text {  real numbers}$

Look at one more:

$$e^{i 2\pi}=1$$

$$(e^{2 \pi i})^i=1^i$$

$$e^{-2 \pi}=1$$

**The error here is that the rule of multiplying exponents as when going to the third line does not apply unmodified with complex exponents**, even if when putting both sides to the power i only the principal value is chosen.